# How to share the uploaded salesforce file automatically

Tags: files

How can I share a file automatically as soon as they are uploaded?

Ineed to write a trigger but on which object?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

To customize file sharing behavior, define an Apex trigger for the ContentDistribution or ContentDocumentLink objects. The ContentDistribution object represents a file shared externally. A ContentDocumentLink represents a file shared with an internal object, such as a user, group, or record.

The ContentDocumentLink object supports triggers before and after these operations: insert, update, delete.

[Create Triggers to Customize File Sharing Behavior](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_content_triggers.htm)

Comment: yes, but am talking salesforce files not attachments.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @C0DEPirate This is pretty close to what I'd call a Link-Only answer